# How do I put a Sequelize model and its assosications into one file?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I found that if I don't put all the associations (hasMany, etc) into one file, I get the following error.

```
   throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
   ^
Error: users.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
  at Function.belongsToMany (C:\app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:49:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app\models\/user.ts:51:6)
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882278/sequelize-assosication-called-with-something-thats-not-a-subclass-of-sequelize/53887155), this can be solved by putting all the associations into one file.

Still, I don't think it's a good approach, because

1. If you want to know about a model, you have to check the model definition (`models/user.ts` in the below example) and the association file (something like `models/index.ts`).
2. the association file can be quite huge if you have many models with associations.

How do I put a Sequelize model and its associations into the same file?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// `models/user.ts`
import { Role } from './role';

const User = sequelizeInstance.define<UserInstance>(
  'users',  {/* fields */},
);

User.belongsToMany(Role, {
  through: 'user_roles',
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  otherKey: 'roleId',
});

export { User };
```

```
// `model/role.ts`.
import { User } from './user';

const Role = sequelizeInstance.define<RoleInstance>(
  'roles', {/* fields */}
);

Role.belongsToMany(User, {
  through: 'user_roles',
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  otherKey: 'roleId',
});

export { Role };
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did.
I declare each model associations in the model declaration, using `associate` property. In your case something like:

```
const Role = sequelizeInstance.define<RoleInstance>(
  'roles', {/* fields */}
);
Role.associate  = function (models) {
   Role.belongsToMany(models.users, {
     through: 'user_roles',
     foreignKey: 'userId',
     otherKey: 'roleId',
   });
});
```

Then in my index file, I wrote few lines to fetch all associations from models declaration and apply them:

```
db.roles = // assign your Role model
db.users = // assign your User model

// setup table associations
Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    // call the associate function and pass reference to all other models
    db[modelName].associate(db); 
  }
});
```

In this way I can keep a compact index, fetch and apply associations dynamically and declare associations in each model

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! This works. Can you please tell me why you put `models` as the argument of `Role.associate  = function (models)...`? The `models` isn't used in the callback, I think

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer; `models` param holds the references to all the other models  defined in `index` file; so in your model file, you can avoid importing the associated model as this will be passed as param of `associate` function

Answer (score 0):

My answer to a similar question asked a few years ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67875061/11558646

Assuming the approach is sound, its advantage is that it doesn't require separate "setting-up-of-all-associations" logic.